# check_mk logwatch monitoring log with date in filename on windows

Tags: windows, monitoring, log-files, check-mk

In windows, is there a way to setup dynamic dates on logs filenames monitoring using check_mk_agent's [logfiles] section??

In linux I know we can use $(date +%Y%m%d), but don't know if it works on windows.

I've got a logfile by day, all of them in the same folder, with names like: *Log_20190219.txt, Log_20190218.txt, Log_20190217.txt, Log_20190216.txt...*

I've setup section in check_mk.ini like this, but it detects a service for each logfile, so it's not what I need:

```
[logfiles]
    textfile = C:\Path\To\Log\Log_*.txt
    crit = *ERRNo*
```

I've tried as well next, but not service has been detected by agent:

```
[logfiles]
    textfile = C:\Path\To\Log\Log_$(date +%Y%m%d).txt
    crit = *ERRNo*
```

Any suggestion in cases like this??